# Add months to a given date

Tags: visual-studio

I want to add, a given number of months by the user, for example 2, to a given dates but I am having same difficulties.
I tried

```
Public Function MyFunction(m_GMonths As Double, m_Given_Date as Date) As Double
    Return  m_Given_Date + m_GMonths
End Function
```

The error I am getting is `Operator '+' is not defined for types 'Date' and 'Double'`

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `m_GMonths` is a `double` - i.e. it's just a number. It's not a number of anything specific, it's just a number. The compiler has no way of knowing what you are adding to the date - 2 days? 2 months? 2 years? That's what the error is telling you - it's nonsensical to add a number to a date. The solution is to use a method which adds months to the date - probably `m_Given_Date.AddMonths(m_GMonths)` or something like that. It would be helpful to tag your question with the language you're using, people might not be able to recognise it so might not know what specific solutions will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `AddMonths`:

```vb
Dim z = DateTime.Now
Dim x = z.AddMonths(2)
```

Comment: I am getting Value of 'Date' cannot be converted. Is not ok to declare as Date ?

Comment: @MihaiDumitru Your method must return `Date` rather `Double`.